# Is javaFX drillDown method on Charts deprecated?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8, pie-chart, drilldown

I saw this [Video from oracle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8riVwFpbNQ)
which shows some amazing animation on pieCharts called drillDown.

I cannot find this method when I am coding, if you have some ideas, please share. Thank you.

Comment: There never was a `drillDown()` method defined on chart. I don't have time to watch the video, but its title is "Custom Charts" - I suspect you are kind of missing the point of "Custom" there...

Comment: its in 26:15 time. take a snap look plss

Comment: That's in the middle of a section of the presentation called "Extending Charts"... presumably he has subclassed `PieChart` to add that functionality. Really, you are missing the whole point of the presentation.

Comment: At 29:47 he says that `DrillDownPieChart` is one of the Ensemble demos. The code looks different to the presentation, but you can see a way to do this if you look at the Ensemble sample code. [Download the JSE samples and demos](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), unzip, and you can look at `demo/javafx_samples/src/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/charts/pie/drilldown/DrilldownPieChartApp.java`. The code is very straightforward.